# Does a router USB port means it supports NAS?

Tags: router, home-networking, nas, storage, usb-storage

My ISP will be sending me a SmartRG SR505n modem/router and I see from the specs that it has a USB 2.0 port. Does this mean that it supports adding a NAS (my extrenal HDD for example?). I checked the datasheet and manual and they say nothing more than it has a USB port. Moreover, can I remotely and securely access this storage or there need be some specialised software or router firmware.

Thanks

Comment: Some routers have a USB port only for USB printer sharing - please be careful. So, a simple answer for the title is "no", but I have no idea about SR505n. I would call the vendor to make it sure.

Answer (score 3):

Having a quick read through the manual:
http://www.start.ca/files/smartrg505n.pdf

It doesn't seem as though you can set it up as a NAS. Usually there are options in the GUI that allow you to set it up as as NAS (Such as on most Netgear routers).

It does however mention updating firmware from a hard drive, so I am assuming that is what the USB port is for

Answer (score 0):

SmartRG user manual only mentions that the USB port provides 5 V power. It does not state anything about connecting any USB device.